# using docker plugin with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using sbt 1,3.6, jdk 11.0.6 & scala 2.13.1.

I am trying to use the sbt native packager with the docker plugin:

```
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

However, when I run **sbt clean**, I get the following error:

```
error: not found: value DockerPlugin
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

I have tried using the following but it has not helped:

```
enablePlugins(sbtdocker.DockerPlugin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the plugin.properties file in the project directory:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.2")
```

Comment: Faced the same issue, then I found this https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/gettingstarted.html where they mention to add the AutoPlugin